# Trigger VSTS pull request build verification based on path filter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a repository with multiple projects. For example, one is an Angular project for the frontend, the other is an Azure Function for the backend.

When code is pushed via pull request we have different builds that are triggered to verify the incoming changes.

However, all of the verification builds are always triggered, even though changes are made to a single project, which resides in a specific directory (For example, only Angular coder is changed, all of it is under /Frontend path).

There is one workaround I'm aware of - Splitting the repository in such way so there will be only a single project in each repository.

This workaround is not suitable for my needs.

Is there any other way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now possible to do this using path filters for pull request policies.
See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/nov-28-vsts

Answer (score 0):

It’s better to split the repository.

Path filter feature of pull request build verification is not supported. There is a similar user voice that you can vote:

[Define multiple builds with path filters on pre-merge pull request build policy](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17780509-define-multiple-builds-with-path-filters-on-pre-me)